# Whether Endianness is a property or hardware or software?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, cpu, endianness

I have read that Intel and AMD follows little endian concept. Whether it is a property of hardware alone, or OS can override it ? I am telling this because processor serial number I am getting from windows and linux are in opposite order.

Comment: Hardware. Intel processors are little endian.  I'm not sure what you mean by "serial number", since only a brief series of Pentium III chips had a serial number concept. There was an uproar over privacy, and the feature removed in subsequent chips.

Comment: Endianness is the order for byte oriented operations of a given processor. So it's a hardware, but it won't produce any results without an OS. While writing this OS a developer should have the exact endiannes in mind so it's a software. No matter what OS you use on the same hardware the endiannes remains the same. It can be little\big\mixed. since it can be mixed - it's also a property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The endianess is based on hardware only.OS cannot overwrite it since it is the order in which data is written/ read from/to hardware. You might be getting the number in opposite order because the driver you are using might be swapping the bytes for you.